# Elasticsearch - search wildcards (contains in strings) and tf-idf scores

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, tf-idf, elasticsearch-query

how can I make a search wildcard and tf-idf scores.
example when I search like this,

```
GET /test_es/_search?explain=true // return idf / dt scores
{
  "explain":true,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "bar^5",
      "fields"  : ["field"]
    }
  }
}
```

it returns idf and td score,
but when I search like with wildcards (contains).

```
GET /test_es/_search?explain=true  // NOT RETURN idf/td score
{
   "explain":true,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "b*",
      "fields"  : ["field"]
    }
  }
}
```

how can I make a search with wildcards (using contains in the string) and include the IDF-TD scores?

for example, I have 3 documents
"**foo**", "**foo bar**", "**foo baz**"
when I search it like that

```
GET /foo2/_search?explain=true
{
   "explain":true,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "fo *",
      "fields"  : ["field"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Elasticsearch Result**

```
    "hits" : [
  {
    "_shard" : "[foo2][0]",
    "_node" : "z8bjI0T1T8Oq6Z2OwFyIKw",
    "_index" : "foo2",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "3",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "field" : "foo bar"
    },
    "_explanation" : {
      "value" : 1.0,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [
        {
          "value" : 1.0,
          "description" : "*:*",
          "details" : [ ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_shard" : "[foo2][0]",
    "_node" : "z8bjI0T1T8Oq6Z2OwFyIKw",
    "_index" : "foo2",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "field" : "foo"
    },
    "_explanation" : {
      "value" : 1.0,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [
        {
          "value" : 1.0,
          "description" : "*:*",
          "details" : [ ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_shard" : "[foo2][0]",
    "_node" : "z8bjI0T1T8Oq6Z2OwFyIKw",
    "_index" : "foo2",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "field" : "foo baz"
    },
    "_explanation" : {
      "value" : 1.0,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [
        {
          "value" : 1.0,
          "description" : "*:*",
          "details" : [ ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But I expect "foo"  should be the first result with having the highest score because it matches %100, am I wrong?

Comment: It's confusing. Do you want `idf-td` in the result or do you expect a particular scoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2:**

> Wildcard Queries basically falls under Term-level queries, and by
> default uses the **constant_score_boolean** method for matching terms.

**By changing the value of the [rewrite parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) you can impact search performance and relevance. It has various options for scoring, you can choose any of them according to your requirement.**

**But according to your use case, you may also use edge_ngram filter.
Edge N-Grams are useful for search-as-you-type queries. To know more about this and the mapping used below refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#analysis-edgengram-tokenizer)**

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index sample data:**

```
{ "title":"foo" }
{ "title":"foo bar" }
{ "title":"foo baz" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "fo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "foo6",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.15965709,        --> Maximum score
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "foo6",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.12343237,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo bar"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "foo6",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.12343237,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "foo baz"
                }
            }
        ]
```

To know more about basics of using Ngrams in Elasticsearch you can refer [this](https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: @e y  please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this was your issue

Comment: @e y Thank u for accepting the answer, it would be great if you can upvote the answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned anything about data that you have taken, I have indexed the following data:

**Index data:**

```
{
    "message": "A fox is a wild animal."
}
{
    "message": "That fox must have killed the hen."
}
{
    "message": "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
GET/{{index-name}}/_search?explain=true 

{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "message"                       ---> You can add more fields here
      ],
      "query": "quick^2 fox*"
    }
  }
}
```

The query above searches all the documents containing `fox`, but here since **boost** is applied to `quick`, so the document containing `quick fox` will have a higher score as compared to other documents.

**This query will return the tf-IDF score.
The boost operator is used, to make one term more relevant than another.**

To know more about this refer to this official documentation on ["Boosting" in dsl-query-string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boosting)

To know more about the tf-IDF algorithm you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.softwaremill.com/6-not-so-obvious-things-about-elasticsearch-422491494aa4)

**If you want to search across multiple fields, you can boost the scores in a certain field**

Refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20query_string,string%20includes%20any%20invalid%20syntax.) to know more.

**Update 1:**

**Index Data :**

```
{
  "title": "foo bar"
}
{
  "title": "foo baz"
}
{
  "title": "foo"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "foo *"         --> You can just add a space between 
                                   foo and *
     }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "foo2",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.9808292,       --> foo matches exactly, so the 
                                           score is maximum
            "_source": {
               "title": "foo"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "foo2",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.1234324,
            "_source": {
               "title": "foo bar"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "foo2",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.1234324,
            "_source": {
               "title": "foo baz"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: @e y did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: thank you for you response but probably I couldn't explain my problem clearly, for example, I have 3 documents 
"foo"
"foo bar"
"foo baz"
 when I search it like that "foo*"  
it gives me the result like that  "foo baz", "foo", "foo bar", three of them same score, but I expect that  "foo" document should be the first result because it matches %100.

Comment: @e y please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this was your issue

Comment: thanks it is correct if I search "foo *",  but if I search "fo *" still  I expect  "foo" should be the first result am I wrong? , elasticsearch returns "foo bar" the first result again

Comment: if I search "fo *" still  I expect  "foo" should be the first result because the match percentage is higher than others